# how to bind grid view, show it and then generate pdf?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, gridview

I have a page on which user select a date range and submit the form. I am picking data as per date range and then binding it  to the gridview. Since I have to also generate pdf just after binding I am using response.write to write the generated pdf file to the user. But the problem is that the gridview never changes. The moment I stops execution after gridbind(return;), the gridview binds properly. After struggling for some time i found out it is happining due to response.write and response.end statement which is used for writing the file.

My question is how to do these two task back to back? so that when user submit the form he sees the gridview with all data and also the file gets downloaded.

right now after gridbinding I generate 1 more link to the generated pdf but the client wants that it should be done in one go instead of 2 .

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using two ways

1. show your data to user and set interval in javascript lets say wait for 1 min and then postback page to download PDF.
2. (RECOMMENDED)create another page say FileDownloader.aspx and open that page in new window using javascript. you can share your data between pages using session, disk, db whatever suits you best.